# $\prod_{k=1}^{100} ( k^2 /(k+1) )= 100!/101,$ right?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, products

$$\prod_{k=1}^{100}( k^2 /(k+1) )= (100!)^2/(101!) = (100!)^2/(101 * 100!) = 100!/101$$

is how I got my answer. Is that correct?

Comment: The notation is not valid. What is the product of? $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{100}$ by itself is meaningless.

Comment: My bad, I fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations are right !!!

$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{100}\frac{k^2}{(k+1)}=(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{100}k^2)*\prod\limits_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{(k+1)}=\frac{(100!)^2}{101!}=\frac{100!}{101}$$

Comment: Sorry about that, I've fixed it now!

Comment: Thank you for the help!